# Enterprise App installation on IOS device using Safari browser issues warning cannot open page address is invalid

Tags: ios, safari, installation, enterprise-library

i am trying to install IOS enterprise application hosted on my server using Safari browser using IOS itms-link.

Scenario:[issue will occur if i try to install the App multiple times]

1. on IOS 8.2 devices(ipad/iphone) if i click on install,
   safari will show pop up for confirmation "do you you wan't to install" with ok and cancel button
2. select  cancel  and try to install again will show popup "do you want to open the app" with ok and cancel button
3. select cancel and try to install again will show popup "Safri cannot open the page because address is invalid"

after this i am not able to install any app hosted on the server same error message will appear "Safri cannot open the page because address is invalid"
for every install click.

if i refresh and try to install app ,works fine app will get install successfully on device

NOTE :
 -  there is no problem with app , if i accept the pop-up do you wan't to install, app will successfully get installed on device
 - on click of install i am doing winow.open("itms-link for the app to download")
 - if i try the same scenario mentioned above on chrome browser ,there is no problem app will successfully get installed

looks like safari is remembering some details about app which i am to trying to install and showing this pop-up

i tried clearing safari cookie and session data after each installation [no-luck]

device log shows "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "ignored" on (null) 
not sure what this log indicating

please help me on this  ,thanks in advance.